# Counting elements in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have a page with a table, say:

```
<table> 
<tr><td>Element1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Element2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to make tests with cucumber and capybara. How can I get the number of table rows in a step definition (it is the only table on the page)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the count of all tr elements in the table.

```
page.all("table tr").count
```